# Как изменить контекст функции chane(this) при нажатии button?

Tags: javascript

Please help!

Мне нужно создать функцию `change()` в скрипте.
Вы можете увидеть вызов этой функции в HTML как `change(this)`
С нажатием кнопки нужно изменить значения функций `First` и `Second`.

Например, должно быть:

```
let first = new First(26, 'Melica', 'human', 'doctor');
let second = new Second(300, 'Michael', 'ghost', 'unemployed', 'count');
```

Таким образом, при нажатии button (`onclick="change(this)"`) функция должна принимать значения функций `First` или `Second`.

Например:

Если я нажму на кнопку с `button.innerText` **first**, функция должна принять значения
`new First(26, 'Melisa', ' human', 'doctor')`.

Обратите внимание, что функции-конструкторы `First` и `Second` имеют значения из конструктора `BASE` и одно собственное.
`First` и `Second` — это прототипы функции `BASE`.

```js
function Base(name, age, species) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.species = species;

  if (this.age < 0) {
    this.age = 0;
  }
}

Base.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}!`);
}

function First(age, name, species, job) {
  Base.call(this, name, age, species);
  this.job = job;

}

First.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
First.prototype.constructor = Base;


function Second(age, name, species, color) {
  Base.call(this, name, age, species);
  this.color = color;
}
Second.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Second.prototype.constructor = Base
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <button class="protoBtn active" onclick="change(this)">none</button>
  <button class="protoBtn" onclick="change(this)">first</button>
  <button class="protoBtn" onclick="change(this)">second</button>
  <button class="protoBtn" onclick="change(this)">third</button>
</div>
```